# How to solve the emmeans error within function?

Tags: r, function, emmeans

It works when I use it by default without function.
CHQ01 is a factor with 5 levels.

```
out <- aov(DF2M[['RMR']] ~ DF2M[['CHQ01']] + AGE + FFM, data = DF2M)
emm <- emmeans::emmeans(out,specs ='CHQ01',)
results <-  summary(emm)[-c(1,4)]
results_vec <- cbind(results[1,],results[2,],results[3,],results[4,],results[5,])
results_vec <- results_vec[ , order(names(results_vec))]
order.list <- c(results_vec %>% select(starts_with('emmean')) %>% names(),
                results_vec %>% select(starts_with('SE')) %>% names(),
                results_vec %>% select(starts_with('lower.CL')) %>% names(),
                results_vec %>% select(starts_with('upper.CL')) %>% names())
results_ord <- results_vec[ ,order.list]
results_ord
```

However, the following error occurs when the emmeans package goes into the function.

```
ano_emm.fun <- function(df,namedep,nameindep) {
out <- aov(df[[nameindep]] ~  (df[[namedep]]) + AGE + FFM, df)
emm <- emmeans(out, specs = namedep)
  results <-  summary(emm)[-c(1,4)]
  results_vec <- cbind(results[1,],results[2,],results[3,],results[4,],results[5,])
  results_vec <- results_vec[ , order(names(results_vec))]
  order.list <- c(results_vec %>% select(starts_with('emmean')) %>% names(),
                  results_vec %>% select(starts_with('SE')) %>% names(),
                  results_vec %>% select(starts_with('lower.CL')) %>% names(),
                  results_vec %>% select(starts_with('upper.CL')) %>% names())
  results_ord <- results_vec[ ,order.list]
  results_ord <- cbind(var= namedep, results_ord)
  return(results_ord)
}
ano_emm.fun(DF2M, 'AGE', 'RMR')
```

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula, data = data, ...) : 
invalid type (NULL) for variable df[[namedep]]
8.
model.frame.default(formula, data = data, ...)
7.
stats::model.frame(formula, data = data, ...)
6.
model.frame(trms, utils::head(data, 2))
5.
.find.coerced(trms, data)
4.
(function (object, at, cov.reduce = mean, cov.keep = get_emm_option("cov.keep"), 
mult.names, mult.levs, options = get_emm_option("ref_grid"), 
data, df, type, regrid, nesting, offset, sigma, nuisance = character(0), 
non.nuisance, wt.nuis = "equal", rg.limit = get_emm_option("rg.limit"), ...
3.
do.call(ref_grid, args)
2.
emmeans(out, specs = namedep)
1.
ano_emm.fun(df = DF2M, namedep = colnames(DF2M[i]), nameindep = "RMR")
```

I made a function because I had to analyze several variables at once, but strangely, when emmeans is in the function, there is an error.
I've tried the as.nuermic, as.factor on varible df[[namedep]], but it doesn't work.

I am sorry that I cannot disclose the dataset. The same problem was found in iris dataset.

```
out <- aov(iris[['Sepal.Length']] ~ iris[['Species']] + Sepal.Width +  Petal.Length, data = iris)
emm <- emmeans::emmeans(out,specs ='Species')

ano_emm.fun <- function(df,namedep,nameindep) {
  out <- aov(df[[nameindep]] ~ df[[namedep]] + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, df)
  emm <- emmeans(out, specs = namedep)
  return(out)
}
ano_emm.fun(iris,'Species','Sepal.Length')
```

Comment: It is a scoping error. Try adding data = df to the emmeans() call.

Comment: @RussLenth Thank you for comments. As you told me, I put data=df in the emmeans function, but the following error appears.  ```emm <- emmeans(out, specs = namedep, data=df)``` ```Error in `[.data.frame`(tbl, , vars, drop = FALSE) :  undefined columns selected```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your error messages closely, we see:

> invalid type (NULL) for variable df[[namedep]]

which implies that it is looking for a variable named `"df[[namedep]]"` rather than `namedep`.
We can solve that issue most elegantly by using `reformulate()` to create the model formula.

Additional minor issues:

- I think you want to return `emm`, not `out`
- By conventional terminology, the left-hand side of the model formula is the *dependent* variable, and the ones on the right-hand side are *independent* variables.

The following revised function does the trick (and also addresses the minor points above)

```
ano_emm.fun <- function(df, nameindep, namedep) {
    fmla <- reformulate(c(nameindep, "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length"),
                        response = namedep)
    out <- aov(fmla, df)
    emm <- emmeans(out, specs = nameindep)
    return(emm)
}
```

Test run:

```
> ano_emm.fun(iris, 'Species', 'Sepal.Length')
 Species    emmean     SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 setosa       6.63 0.1672 145     6.30     6.96
 versicolor   5.67 0.0639 145     5.54     5.80
 virginica    5.23 0.1259 145     4.98     5.48

Confidence level used: 0.95
```